# What is "total" from ls -al?

Tags: c, format, ls, stat

I have been tasked to mimic the command `ls -alU --time-style=long-iso`. While i have it nearly down i don't quite understand what that first like of total is. I understand its the total amount of blocks used *2 or something similar but i'm not understanding where that number is coming from and where to find it using stat?

**CODE**

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <grp.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    DIR *mydir;
    struct dirent *myfile;
    struct stat myStat;
    struct passwd *pwd;
    int s;
    struct tm lt;
    char buf[1024];
    struct group *gf;
    mydir = opendir("./");

    while((myfile = readdir(mydir)) != NULL)
    {
        stat(myfile->d_name, &myStat);
        if((stat(myfile->d_name, &myStat) ) == 0){
            pwd = getpwuid(myStat.st_uid);
        }
        gf = getgrgid(myStat.st_gid);
        time_t t = myStat.st_mtime;
        localtime_r(&t, &lt);
        char timebuf[80];
        char timebuf2[80];

        strftime(timebuf, sizeof(timebuf), "%F", &lt);
        strftime(timebuf2, sizeof(timebuf2), "%R", &lt);
        printf( (S_ISDIR(myStat.st_mode)) ? "d" : "-");
        printf( (myStat.st_mode & S_IRUSR) ? "r" : "-");
        printf( (myStat.st_mode & S_IWUSR) ? "w" : "-");
        printf( (myStat.st_mode & S_IXUSR) ? "x" : "-");
        printf( (myStat.st_mode & S_IRGRP) ? "r" : "-");
        printf( (myStat.st_mode & S_IWGRP) ? "w" : "-");
        printf( (myStat.st_mode & S_IXGRP) ? "x" : "-");
        printf( (myStat.st_mode & S_IROTH) ? "r" : "-");
        printf( (myStat.st_mode & S_IWOTH) ? "w" : "-");
        printf( (myStat.st_mode & S_IXOTH) ? "x" : "-");
        printf(" ");
        printf("%ld ", myStat.st_nlink);
        if(pwd != 0){
            printf("%s %s %ld\t%s %s %s\n", pwd->pw_name, gf->gr_name, (long)myStat.st_size, timebuf, timebuf2, myfile->d_name);
        }else  {

            printf("%d %s %ld\t%s %s %s\n", myStat.st_uid, gf->gr_name, (long)myStat.st_size, timebuf, timebuf2, myfile->d_name);
            printf("\n");
        } 
    }
    closedir(mydir);
}
```

**CURRENT OUTPUT**

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 user user    46 2019-04-03 21:17 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 user root    19 2019-04-03 18:33 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user     6 2019-04-03 18:34 .che
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  1895 2019-04-03 21:17 lsdir.c
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user 13304 2019-04-03 21:17 lsdir
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 3 user user    46 2019-04-03 21:17 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 user root    19 2019-04-03 18:33 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user     6 2019-04-03 18:34 .che
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  1895 2019-04-03 21:17 lsdir.c
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user 13304 2019-04-03 21:17 lsdir
```

Comment: How the number is calculated is explained in the section on `-l` here: https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/What-information-is-listed.html

Comment: For adjusting field width and alignment, read up on printf.

Comment: ahhhhh okay so its the total amount of blocks set aside for disk allocation. But how using stat can i get this number?

Comment: `struct stat` has a field that will probably be helpful. Just remember to take the difference between the block size it counts and the block size that is displayed into account - you already touched on that in your question, though the math was wrong.